# Mocking custom provider injected into provider when unit testing Angular in Jasmine

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I'm unit testing a provider in Jasmine, which relies on another provider. There's no configuration associated with this provider. When mocking a provider, I've read you're supposed to use something like

```
beforeEach(module(function ($provide) {
    mockInjectedProvider = { };
    $provide.value('injected', mockInjectedProvider );
}));
```

which works fine for me when injecting a custom provider into a service. When injecting them into a provider it doesn't work though. The code doesn't fail, but what gets executed when testing is the actual provider, not the mocked one. Abstracted example below.

```
var mockInjectedProvider;

beforeEach(function () {
    module('myModule');
});

beforeEach(module(function ($provide) {
    mockInjectedProvider = {
        myFunc: function() {
            return "testvalue"
            }
        }
    };
    $provide.value('injected', mockInjectedProvider );
}));

beforeEach(inject(function (_base_) {
    baseProvider = _base_;
}));

it("injectedProvider should be mocked", function () {
    var resultFromMockedProvider = baseProvider.executeMyFuncFromInjected();
    expect(resultFromMockedProvider).toEqual("testvalue");
}); // Here instead of using my mock it executes the actual dependency
```

In the `$provide.value` statement I've tried including both `injected` and `injectedProvider`, as well as using `$provide.provider` and mocking a `$get` function on it but nothing seems to work. I just can't get it to mock away the actual provider. Abstracted base provider looks like this.

```
(function (ng, module) {
    module.provider("base",
        ["injectedProvider", function (injectedProvider) {
            this.executeMyFuncFromInjected= function() {
                return injectedProvider.myFunc(); // let's say this returns "realvalue"
            }
            this.$get = function () {
                return this;
            };
        }]
    );
})(window.angular, window.angular.module("myModule"));
```

Everything in my code is working except the Jasmine mocking.

Comment: i think you have to use the method `provider` instead of the the `value` method. like so `$provider.provider('injected', mockInjectedProvider)`;

Comment: Like I said, tried `$provide.provider` already. End result is exactly the same.

Comment: Yep sorry. Actually I realize that in fact you should not test the function that delegates to the injected provider function but test directly the injected provider function, because you have relevant logic in the example. Or instead of mocking the service to add an spy on the injected provider function and test if the function was called `expect(injectedProvider.myFunc).toHaveBeenCalled()`

Comment: I don't need to test the injected provider, what I need to do is mock away the value it returns. The "injectedProvider should be mocked" test is just an example to show how this is failing.

Comment: Ok, so you don't need to mock the hole provider but the return value, use `spyOn($inject(function(_injected_){return _injected_;}), 'myFunc').andReturn({/*whatever you need*/})`

Comment: Found the solution, it was 
    `beforeEach(inject(function (_injected_) {
        spyOn(_injected_, "myFunc").and.returnValue("testvalue");
    }));`. If you put it in an answer I'd gladly accept it!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81633/discussion-between-raulucco-and-jan).

Comment: When you `$provide.provider`, remember to drop the 'Provider' suffix from the provider's name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case is better to just mock the return value instead of the provider.

```
  var mockInjectedProvider;

beforeEach(function () {
    module('myModule');
});

beforeEach(inject(function (_injected_) { 
  spyOn(_injected_, "myFunc").and.returnValue("testvalue");
}));

beforeEach(inject(function (_base_) {
    baseProvider = _base_;
}));

it("injectedProvider should be mocked", function () {
    var resultFromMockedProvider = baseProvider.executeMyFuncFromInjected();
    expect(resultFromMockedProvider).toEqual("testvalue");
}); // Here instead of using my mock it executes the actual dependency
```

Comment: Thanks a million for this. Had been struggling with this for way too long!